# Making a div center inside another div

Tags: html, css

I am new at html coding. I have been needing help with making a div in the middle of another div. Can anyone help me please.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="promo">
        <a href="link.com">Get Coupons!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want promo to be in the middle of wrapper. How do I tell code to make it center. I have tried class = "center" but it doesn't work. I have tried style="center" but it doesn't work.

Please. thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to center the text within the `.wrapper`?

Comment: Can you share your CSS as well?

Comment: The solution depends in part on your existing CSS. Please include your existing CSS in your question. You also might want to check the "related" sidebar on the right side of this page for ideas.

Comment: Hi I want the div centered..

Comment: Centered horizontally? Centered vertically? Both? Does the containing div have width/height? Does the inner div have width/height?

Comment: Isn't this question a `duplicate`?

Comment: This certainly is a duplicate. The above question's answers give several methods that could be used to accomplish OP's goals (unless perhaps he's trying to center vertically as well, but that's really 2 questions.

Comment: Centered Horizantally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO.

This question has been asked many times on this site. The most common way of achieving this is to set the margin to auto.

The reason why class="center" does not work is because the class attribute assigns attributes to css and some. Currently you are telling the promo div to look for a class that does not exist. This is how you create the css for that.

```
.promo{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
 }
```

You may also do the longer way of:

```
.promo{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
 }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewJamesMP/d64d4u2m/) is a working fiddle to get you started. I have also added `text-align: center;` which will center your text in the promo div! (If that is what you want.)

Comment: what if height and width of both parent and child are set to 100%? this solution doesnt work for all cases.

Comment: @SantiagoNicolasRoca - This is correct. However, OP didn't describe/ ask the question well enough. Also, great jQuery solution. However OP didn't add a jQuery or Javascript tag to the question. So I stayed away from using it.

Comment: So, you should write a question under the post to clarify any doubt or provide an answer that can solve every case.

Comment: showDev asked any question I had under the post. At the time the question did not have an answer yet so I wrote one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want the div centered horizontally on the page, you can add this to your existing div to do so:

```
 style="display: table; margin: 0 auto"
```

Full code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="promo" style="display: table; margin: 0 auto";>
        <a href="link.com">Get Coupons!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this function, even though its not the best way of doing it in most of the cases, in others cases its the only way to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".center").each(function(){
   var height = parseInt($(this).parent().css("height"));
   var width = parseInt($(this).parent().css("width"));
   $(this).parent().css("overflow", "hidden");
   $(this).css({
     "margin-top" : ( height - parseInt($(this).css("height"))) / 2,
     "margin-left" : ( width - parseInt($(this).css("width"))) / 2
   });
  });
});
```

just set class="center" on the element you need to center and you are good to go.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="promo center">
        <a href="link.com">Get Coupons!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hvsrz9f/)

Comment: I don't understand this..

Comment: are you using jquery? if you are you need to paste my code at the bottom of your html and add to class attribute center on those elements you need to center. In a moment ill provide a working fiddle as example. Ive just edited my code so be carefull to use this version because the previous one was wrong.

Comment: If you belive this is the most accurate answer please mark it as such for future searchs.

Comment: I didnt yuse this answer. I used the one that is markd correct.